# Merging rows that have same credentials -pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do can I merge two rows in a pyspark dataframe that satisfy a condition?

Example:

**dataframe**

```
+---+---+------+                                                                
|src|dst|weight|
+---+---+------+
|  8|  7|     1|
|  1|  1|    93|
|  1|  4|     1|
|  4|  4|     2|
|  4|  1|     3|
|  1|  7|     1|
+---+---+------+
```

**condition: `(df.src,df.dst) == (df.dst,df.src)`**

**expected output**

summed the weight and deleted (4,1)

```
+---+---+------+                                                                
|src|dst|weight|
+---+---+------+
|  8|  7|     1|
|  1|  1|    93|
|  1|  4|     4| #
|  4|  4|     2|
|  1|  7|     1|
+---+---+------+
```

or

summed the weights and deleted (1,4)

```
+---+---+------+                                                                
|src|dst|weight|
+---+---+------+
|  8|  7|     1|
|  1|  1|    93|
|  4|  4|     2|
|  4|  1|     4| #
|  1|  7|     1|
+---+---+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `src_dst` column with the sorted array of `src` and `dst`, then get the sum of weights for each `src_dst`, and remove duplicate rows of `src_dst`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'src_dst', 
    F.sort_array(F.array('src', 'dst'))
).withColumn(
    'weight', 
    F.sum('weight').over(Window.partitionBy('src_dst'))
).dropDuplicates(['src_dst']).drop('src_dst')

df2.show()
+---+---+------+
|src|dst|weight|
+---+---+------+
|  1|  7|     1|
|  1|  1|    93|
|  1|  4|     4|
|  8|  7|     1|
|  4|  4|     2|
+---+---+------+
```